# Ruby on Rails decorator for caching a result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, decorator, memoization

In Python, you can write a decorator for memoizing a function's response.

Is there something similar for Ruby on Rails?  I have a model's method that makes a query, which I would like to cache.

I know I can do something inside the method, like:

```
def foo(param)
  if self.cache[param].nil?
    self.cache[param] = self.get_query_result(param)
  else
    self.cache[param]
  end
end
```

However, given that I would do this often, I'd prefer a decorator syntax. It is clearer and better IMO.

Is there something like this for Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this using custom accessors, instance variables, and the `||=` operator:

```
def foo
  @foo ||= something_or_other
end
```

`something_or_other` could be a private method on the same class that returns the object that `foo` should be.

**EDIT**

Here's a slightly more complicated solution that lets you cache any method based on the arguments used to call them.

```
class MyClass
  attr_reader :cache
  def initialize
    @cache = {}
  end

  class << self
    def cacheable(symbol)
      alias_method :"_#{symbol}_uncached", symbol

      define_method(symbol) do |*args|
        cache[[symbol, *args]] ||= (send :"_#{symbol}_uncached", *args)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

How this works:

```
class MyClass
  def foo(a, b)
    a + b
  end

  cacheable :foo
end
```

First, the method is defined normally. Then the class method `cacheable` is called, which aliases the original method to a new name, then redefines it under the original name to be executed only if it's not already cached. It first checks the cache for anything using the same method and arguments, returns the value if present, and executes the original method if not.

Comment: Hmm, I guess this isn't really a good solution to your question. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html:

There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things.

-- Phil Karlton

Rails has a lot of built in caching(including query caching). You might not need to do anything:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Here is a recent blog post about problems with roll your own caching:

http://cmme.org/tdumitrescu/blog/2014/01/careful-what-you-memoize/